# Updating Google Cloud Speech API protobuf gradle to 0.8.5 duplicate libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-speech-api, protobuf-java

After updating to protobuf gradle to 0.8.5 of this project
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech, I received this error message:

Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream 
Not sure what to remove

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there are some additional dependencies. This was simply to make the google cloud speech project hosted on Github work.

It is important to keep in mind to use this in the dependencies section.

```
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
```

Also apply the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
```

For which in the build.gradle of the project we must have the classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
```

However, we must have the repository active

```
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
```

This is my app gradle file.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
    grpcVersion = '1.12.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions 'version'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.cloud.android.speech"
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    signingConfigs {
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/api'
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/logging'
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/longrunning'
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/rpc'
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/speech/v1'
                srcDir 'src/main/proto/google/type'
            }

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // Minimum version with platform multi-dex support
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // Minimum version that can run gRPC (TLS extension)
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    // gRPC
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'

    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
    // OAuth2 for Google API
    implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    // Tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                // In most cases you don't need the full Java output
                // if you use the lite output.
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task copySecretKey(type: Copy) {
    def File secretKey = file "$System.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
    from secretKey.getParent()
    include secretKey.getName()
    into 'src/main/res/raw'
    rename secretKey.getName(), "credential.json"
}
preBuild.dependsOn(copySecretKey)
```

This one is the gradle file of the project

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
        google()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
//        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using gradle 4 and gradle-plugin 3

I hope I've helped

[Google cloud speech](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech)

Comment: Can you highlight the parts that are crucial to solving the problem?

Comment: Although this question is something old, I simply answer the question. because the google repositories are for the old versions of android studio and gradle.